# Monotone convergence theorem, how can we take the limit of t

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was reading the proof for the monotone convergence theorem for lebesgue measurable functions on [wiki page here.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Monotone_convergence_theorem#/Proof_4) Below's a screen capture from step 3. [image]

I believe I understood step 3. Please note that we take $t \in (0,1)$. And the very reason that we cannot take $t = 1$ gives us the contradiction in step 3c. However, when we come to the final step of the proof here's what we see:
[image: step 5]

I really don't understand how can we just take the limit as t is going to 1. We know that $\forall k , f_{k} \leq f_{k+1}$ and $\lim_{k -> \infty} f_k = f$. and $s \leq f$ so to me the only thing that yields $ t \int_{X} s d\mu \leq lim_{k -> \infty} \int_X f_k d\mu$ accurate according to me is the fact that $ t < 1$. So how can we casually take the limit and say that the equality still holds? It was the reason we claimed a contradiction at step 3. Then why don't we say in step 3c: $ f(x_0) \leq t . s(x_0)$. Let's take $t -> 1$ so $ f(x_0) \leq s(x_0)$. So now we have an $x_0$ in our hands that is not in the union of Borel sets. Why can't we just do that?